# How to change HintRequest's dialog box with custom one?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have just managed to create hintRequest to get user's phone number and now I want to change it's dialog box with custom one or change dialog's elements.

[image]

For example i would like to change **Continue with** text
Here is the sample of my code:

```
private void requestHint() {
        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                .build();

        CredentialPickerConfig conf  = new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                .setShowAddAccountButton(true)
                .build();

        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .setHintPickerConfig(conf)
                .build();

        PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
                apiClient, hintRequest);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
                    RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you find out an answer?

Comment: I also need this. The default picker looks pretty basic.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
CredentialPickerConfig conf  = new CredentialPickerConfig.Builder()
                                  .setPrompt(CredentialPickerConfig.Prompt.SIGN_UP)
                                  .setShowAddAccountButton(true)
                                  .build();
```

i saw it on the Google developers websites
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApgEs.png)

Comment: How is this custom?